# Is the array creation happening on every foreach loop?

Tags: c#, javascript, php, arrays, foreach

I find myself doing this:

```
string states = "this,that,theother";

foreach(string state in states.Split(','))
{

}
```

And I wonder; Is the `states` string being split on every foreach loop?

This example is in c# but **do other programming languages behave differently**?

Do PHP and JavaScript split on each foreach loop?

Comment: Not my downvotes, but fwiw, string.Split() is typically a horrible way to parse csv data in any language, and if this is really just your hard-coded sample there's a better, nearly as concise, way in C# to define a sequence.

Answer (score -1):

From a .NET perspective:

No, the `state.Split()` occurs one time.

Other languages??  I have no idea what you mean.  You should retag your question as `php` or `javascript` even though I'm quite certain that javascript would behave the same.

Comment: `do other programming languages behave differently` ?